# Reporting Services 2005 Online Training Resources

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have a bit of reporting services know how but I'm looking to expand my knowledge.

Does anyone have any recommendations on (free) online training materials for this (2005 unfortunatley)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms159106%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx